# Compare two large files and combine matching information

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv, multiprocessing

I have two fairly hefty files, JSON (185,000 Lines) and CSV (650,000). I need to iterate through each dict in the JSON file then within that iterate through each part in `part_numbers` and compare it to get the first three letters from where that part is found in the CSV.

For some reason I'm having a hard time doing this properly. The first version of my script was way too slow, so I'm trying to speed it up

JSON Example:

```
[
    {"category": "Dryer Parts", "part_numbers": ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "PQR"], "parent_category": "Dryers"},
    {"category": "Washer Parts", "part_numbers": ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "PQR"], "parent_category": "Washers"},
    {"category": "Sink Parts", "part_numbers": ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "PQR"], "parent_category": "Sinks"},
    {"category": "Other Parts", "part_numbers": ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "PQR"], "parent_category": "Others"}
]
```

The CSV:

```
WCI|ABC
WPL|DEF
BSH|GHI
WCI|JKL
```

The end dict would look like below:

```
{"category": "Other Parts",
 "part_numbers": ["WCIABC","WPLDEF","BSHGHI","JKLWCI"...]}
```

Here's an example of what I've made so far although, it returns `IndexError: list index out of range` at `if (part.rstrip() == row[1]):`:

```
import csv
import json
from multiprocessing import Pool

def find_part(item):
    data = {
        'parent_category': item['parent_category'],
        'category': item['category'],
        'part_numbers': []
    }

    for part in item['part_numbers']:
        for row in reader:
            if (part.rstrip() == row[1]):
                data['part_numbers'].append(row[0] + row[1])

    with open('output.json', 'a') as outfile:
        outfile.write('    ')
        json.dump(data, outfile)
        outfile.write(',\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    catparts = json.load(open('catparts.json', 'r'))
    partfile = open('partfile.csv', 'r')
    reader = csv.reader(partfile, delimiter='|')


    with open('output.json', 'w+') as outfile:
        outfile.write('[\n')

    p = Pool(50)
    p.map(find_part, catparts)

    with open('output.json', 'a') as outfile:
        outfile.write('\n]')
```

Comment: What is `row` at that point?  How many previous lines have you processed?  Also, can you post *minimal* code (per the posting guidelines), or is the file reading a seminal part of the problem?

Comment: The file reading isn't really the issue. It's more about how to do this efficiently. What more code do you need?

Comment: Not more code ... *less*.  However, I think I spotted it without being able to run the code.

Comment: When I run your code with the sample input files, I get a `KeyError: 'parent_category'` on the line `'parent_category': item['parent_category'],` in the `find_part()` function — so am unable to reproduce the "incorrect index error" problem mentioned.

Comment: @martineau Sorry! I am using a key that I forgot to include in the json sample. It's missing `parent_category`

Comment: @RyanScottCady: OK, but now I'm getting `NameError: name 'reader' is not defined` in the `find_part()` function.

Comment: That's odd. You may try placing the reader assignment above the definition of `find_part()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in a comment, your code (now) gives me a `NameError: name 'reader'` is not defined in the `find_part()` function. The fix was to move the creation of the `csv.reader` into the function. I also changed how the file was being opened to use a `with` context manager and a `newline` argument. This also solves the problem of a bunch of separate tasks all trying to read the same csv file at the same time.

Your approach is very inefficient because it reads the entire `'partfile.csv'` file for every part in `item['part_numbers']`. Nevertheless, the following seems to work:

```
import csv
import json
from multiprocessing import Pool

def find_part(item):
    data = {
        'parent_category': item['parent_category'],
        'category': item['category'],
        'part_numbers': []
    }

    for part in item['part_numbers']:
        with open('partfile.csv', newline='') as partfile:  # open csv in Py 3.x
            for row in csv.reader(partfile, delimiter='|'):
                if part.rstrip() == row[1]:
                    data['part_numbers'].append(row[0] + row[1])

    with open('output.json', 'a') as outfile:
        outfile.write('    ')
        json.dump(data, outfile)
        outfile.write(',\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    catparts = json.load(open('carparts.json', 'r'))

    with open('output.json', 'w+') as outfile:
        outfile.write('[\n')

    p = Pool(50)
    p.map(find_part, catparts)

    with open('output.json', 'a') as outfile:
        outfile.write(']')
```

Here's a significantly more efficient version that only reads the entire `'partfile.csv'` file **once** per subprocess:

```
import csv
import json
from multiprocessing import Pool

def find_part(item):
    data = {
        'parent_category': item['parent_category'],
        'category': item['category'],
        'part_numbers': []
    }

    with open('partfile.csv', newline='') as partfile:  # open csv for reading in Py 3.x
        partlist = [row for row in csv.reader(partfile, delimiter='|')]

    for part in item['part_numbers']:
        part = part.rstrip()
        for row in partlist:
            if row[1] == part:
                data['part_numbers'].append(row[0] + row[1])

    with open('output.json', 'a') as outfile:
        outfile.write('    ')
        json.dump(data, outfile)
        outfile.write(',\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    catparts = json.load(open('carparts.json', 'r'))

    with open('output.json', 'w+') as outfile:
        outfile.write('[\n')

    p = Pool(50)
    p.map(find_part, catparts)

    with open('output.json', 'a') as outfile:
        outfile.write(']')
```

While you could read the `'partfile.csv'` data into memory in the main task and pass it as an argument to the `find_part()` subtasks, doing so would just mean that the data would have to be pickled and unpickled for every process. You would need to run some timing tests to determine if that would be faster than using the `csv` module to explicitly read it, as shown above.

Also note that it would also be more efficient to preprocess the data load from the `'carparts.json'` file and strip trailing whitespace from the first elem in every row before submitting tasks to the `Pool` because then you wouldn't need to do the `part = part.rstrip()` in `find_part()` over and over. Again, I don't know if doing so would be worth the effort or not—and only timing tests can determine the answer.

Comment: Would this answer cause issues with multiple processes trying to open the file?

Comment: @RyanScottCady: No, it will not cause a problem since the processes are all just trying to read the file. Is `partfile.csv` very big?

Comment: `partfile.csv` is 650k lines. So it's not super large. I am wondering if there is an issue to just read its contents into a dictionary haha. I tried your solution though and it is working!

Comment: Ryan: That's not very big by today's standards, so you could read it into memory and pass it to each process. There will be some overhead introduced in doing that, though  — it needs to be pickled and unpickled for each process, which might not be much faster. I'm looking into a solution for that and will update my answer accordingly—if it proves viable that is...

Answer (score 1):

I think I found it.  Your CSV reader is like many other file access methods: you read the file sequentially, and then hit EOF.  When you try to do the same with the second part, the file is already at EOF, and the first `read` attempt returns a null result; this has no second element.

If you want to access all of the records again, you need to reset the file bookmark.  The easiest way is to seek back to byte 0 with

```
partfile.seek(0)
```

Another way is to close and reopen the file.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: Thanks for your input! Where would I add this snippet to my code?

Comment: You insert that when you want to go back to the start of the file.  Where does that fit in your control and data flow?

Answer (score 0):

This should work as long as all the part numbers exist in the csv.

```
import json

# read part codes into a dictionary
with open('partfile.csv') as fp:
    partcodes = {}
    for line in fp:
        code, number = line.strip().split('|')
        partcodes[number] = code

with open('catparts.json') as fp:
    catparts = json.load(fp)

# modify the part numbers/codes 
for cat in catparts:
    cat['part_numbers'] = [partcodes[n] + n for n in cat['part_numbers']]

# output
with open('output.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(catparts, fp)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the difference between using `with open()` vs just using something like: `file = open('file', 'r')`?

Comment: Also, I received an error with your code: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` I'm guessing this is due to the fact that the files are so big. The CSV has 650,000 lines and the JSON file 185,000

Comment: It's probably caused by some line in partfile.csv with multiple `|` in it. This is just example code, so I make some assumption about consistent input data. In production code, you would have to handle malformed input.